# Something in AsyncTask Blocking the UI - causing interface to halt briefly

Tags: java, android

I have a listview that is populated thru SQLite with cache data.  After it finishes loading. in the background I check for new data and get a returned `JSON` result from a `MySQL` db.

In my `onPostExecute` of this background `task`, when this code is ran (the code below), and  while it is being looped thru (a maximum of 50 loops), the UI thread is blocked and scrolling a `ListView` is not possible.  Here is code:

```
if (result.length() != 0) {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;

                for (int ii = 0; ii < jArray.length(); ii++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);

                    item = json_data.getString("item");
                    cat = json_data.getString("category");
                    user = json_data.getString("username");
                    userId = json_data.getLong("user_id");
                    review = json_data.getString("review");
                    reviewId = json_data.getLong("review_id");
                    itemId = json_data.getLong("item_id");
                    commentCount = json_data.getLong("commentCount");
                    url = json_data.getString("name");
                    url = pathUrl + url; // for profile icon
                    date = json_data.getString("date");
                    rating = json_data.getDouble("rating");
                    upVote = json_data.getLong("good");
                    wiki = json_data.getString("wiki");


                    watchItems.add(item);
                    watchCats.add(cat);
                    watchUsers.add(user);
                    watchReviews.add(review);
                    watchUrl.add(url);
                    watchDateList.add(date);
                    watchWikiList.add(wiki);

                    watchItemIdList.add(String.valueOf(itemId));
                    watchUserIds.add(String.valueOf(userId));
                    watchReviewId.add(String.valueOf(reviewId));
                    watchRating.add(String.valueOf(rating));
                    watchCommentCount.add(String.valueOf(commentCount));
                    watchUpVote.add(String.valueOf(upVote));

                    Rateit.haveFollowing = "1";

                    if (Rateit.isUserLoggedIn == true) {
                        boolean oldReview = datasource
                                .getReviewIds(reviewId);
                        if (!oldReview) {
                            // Cache Network Items
                            datasource.createTrendWatch(itemId, item,
                                    review, reviewId, cat, user,
                                    String.valueOf(userId), url, date,
                                    commentCount, rating, upVote, 0,
                                    wiki);  
                        }
                    }


                        FollowingItems wti = new FollowingItems(
                                Long.valueOf(watchItemIdList.get(i)),
                                watchItems.get(i), watchCats.get(i),
                                watchReviews.get(i),
                                Long.valueOf(watchReviewId.get(i)),
                                watchUsers.get(i),
                                Long.valueOf(watchUserIds.get(i)),
                                watchUrl.get(i), watchDateList.get(i),
                                Long.valueOf(watchCommentCount.get(i)),
                                Double.valueOf(watchRating.get(i)),
                                Long.valueOf(watchUpVote.get(i)),
                                watchWikiList.get(i++));
                        watchingListObject.add(wti);

                }
            }
```

Why is this happening? And how can I prevent my code to prevent this?  Are there any optimizations I can make?

**Edit:  Someone below requested full `task` code.**

```
Below repeats the code above but in context with entire task.

    public static class FollowingTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        protected InputStream is = null;
        protected String result = "";
        protected String userId;
        protected ArrayList<FollowingItems> watchingListObject;
        protected Context mContext;

        public FollowingTask(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (mContext != null && (fromRefresh == false)) {
                ((MainFragmentActivity) mContext)
                        .setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
            }

            resetLists();

            if (PrefActivity.getUserLoggedInStatus(mContext) == true) {
                userId = PrefActivity.getLoggedInUserId(mContext);
            } else {
                userId = "-1";
            }

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            datasource.purgeItemWatchingTable();
            Log.d("1", "Back");
            String url_select = "http://www.---.info/includes_mc_php/featured_watching.php";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userId));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v2", "true"));



            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            String pathUrl = Rateit.PROFILE_PIC_URL;
            String item, cat, user, review, url, date, following, wiki;
            long itemId, reviewId, userId, commentCount, upVote;
            double rating;
            int i = 0;
            watchingListObject = new ArrayList<FollowingItems>();


            try {
                String c = String.valueOf(result.charAt(0));

                if (c.equals("{")) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    following = jsonObject.getString("following");
                    if (following.equals("0")) {
                        Rateit.haveFollowing = "0";
                    }

                } else {

                    if (result.length() != 0) {
                        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                        JSONObject json_data = null;

                        for (int ii = 0; ii < jArray.length(); ii++) {
                            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(ii);

                            item = json_data.getString("item");
                            cat = json_data.getString("category");
                            user = json_data.getString("username");
                            userId = json_data.getLong("user_id");
                            review = json_data.getString("review");
                            reviewId = json_data.getLong("review_id");
                            itemId = json_data.getLong("item_id");
                            commentCount = json_data.getLong("commentCount");
                            url = json_data.getString("name");
                            url = pathUrl + url; // for profile icon
                            date = json_data.getString("date");
                            rating = json_data.getDouble("rating");
                            upVote = json_data.getLong("good");
                            wiki = json_data.getString("wiki");


                            watchItems.add(item);
                            watchCats.add(cat);
                            watchUsers.add(user);
                            watchReviews.add(review);
                            watchUrl.add(url);
                            watchDateList.add(date);
                            watchWikiList.add(wiki);

                            watchItemIdList.add(String.valueOf(itemId));
                            watchUserIds.add(String.valueOf(userId));
                            watchReviewId.add(String.valueOf(reviewId));
                            watchRating.add(String.valueOf(rating));
                            watchCommentCount.add(String.valueOf(commentCount));
                            watchUpVote.add(String.valueOf(upVote));

                            Rateit.haveFollowing = "1";

                            if (Rateit.isUserLoggedIn == true) {
                                boolean oldReview = datasource
                                        .getReviewIds(reviewId);
                                if (!oldReview) {
                                    // Cache Network Items
                                    datasource.createTrendWatch(itemId, item,
                                            review, reviewId, cat, user,
                                            String.valueOf(userId), url, date,
                                            commentCount, rating, upVote, 0,
                                            wiki);  
                                }
                            }


                                FollowingItems wti = new FollowingItems(
                                        Long.valueOf(watchItemIdList.get(i)),
                                        watchItems.get(i), watchCats.get(i),
                                        watchReviews.get(i),
                                        Long.valueOf(watchReviewId.get(i)),
                                        watchUsers.get(i),
                                        Long.valueOf(watchUserIds.get(i)),
                                        watchUrl.get(i), watchDateList.get(i),
                                        Long.valueOf(watchCommentCount.get(i)),
                                        Double.valueOf(watchRating.get(i)),
                                        Long.valueOf(watchUpVote.get(i)),
                                        watchWikiList.get(i++));
                                watchingListObject.add(wti);

                                Log.d("1", "Post 2");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Rateit.haveFollowing = "2";
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                Rateit.haveFollowing = "2";
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("1", "Post COMPLETE");
            mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();

            // Reset Trending List on Pull-to-Refresh
            if (mContext != null) {

                if (watchUsers.size() == 0) {
                    l.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv.setTypeface(TypeFace.get(mContext, Rateit.BPREPLAY));
                } else {
                    l.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                if (mContext != null) {

                    listView.setAdapter(null);

                    if (watchItems.size() > 0) {
                        wAdapter = new FollowingAdapter(mContext,
                                watchingListObject, TypeFace.get(mContext,
                                        Rateit.BPREPLAY), TypeFace.get(
                                        mContext, Rateit.ROBOTO_LIGHT),
                                TypeFace.get(mContext, Rateit.ROBOTO_THIN),
                                TypeFace.get(mContext, Rateit.ROBOTO_REGULAR));
                        listView.setAdapter(wAdapter);
                    }

                }
            }

            if (mContext != null && (fromRefresh == false)) {
                ((MainFragmentActivity) mContext)
                        .setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                MainFragmentActivity.dismissDialog(mContext);

            }

            fromRefresh = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. It will block the UI. `doInBackground` runs in the background. You should perform heavy opertaions in the `doInBackground` not in `onPostExecute`..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare  Yes, but I don't believe I can parse JSON items in `doInBackground`

Comment: just hint: if you want to load data from your SQLite database you should consider a `Louders` not asyncTask

Comment: Any reason why? Can you post the full code for `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @Coderji  I will look into that.  Though Loading FROM the `task` doesn't seem to block UI thread at all.  That code isn't shown above.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare  I added my entire `task` in full; though much of it may not be relevant to the issue.

Comment: I see.. in my opinion, you can move the parsing etc from the `onPostExecute` to `doInBackground` and use the `onPostExecute` just for binding the processed information to the UI. Give this a try and let me know..

Comment: @AmulyaKhare  It looks like, you sir, were correct.  I moved the bulk of that in `doInBackround`; no crash, UI not blocked; go ahead and mark that as the answer.

Comment: @KickingLettuce done that. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Why do you even go through strings for your assignments? Use `getLong` instead of `Long.valueOf( getString() )` -- all those temporary allocations are contributing to your problem (but yes, you'd be better of parsing in `doInBackground()`)

Comment: @323go  Thanks... I have cleaned that up in other areas, forgot here.  Glad you reminded me on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread. It will block the UI. `doInBackground` runs in the background. You should perform heavy opertaions in the `doInBackground` (not in `onPostExecute`)

Solution: you should move the parsing etc. from the `onPostExecute` to `doInBackground` and use the `onPostExecute` just for binding the processed information to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest as first thing to profile that code and measure how much time exactly is spent to execute it. This way at least you understand if your problem is really here or somewhere else

Comment: I did, I put a `Log` in this loop and watched on my device as the UI was blocked, the Loop was continuing.  This is it. (the code above).